# Verify which key was used to connect to SSH

Tags: ssh

I usually connect to a particular server with a specific key, like so:

```
$ ssh -i key.pem ec2-user@server
```

Yesterday I realised that the key I have been using isn't actually in `ec2-user`'s `authorized_keys` file. There is only one key listed, which I do also have on my machine.

I am trying to understand how I've been able to successfully connect using the above command. Is there a way to get the `ssh` program to explicity describe which key it used to connect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When providing `-v` in the connection command of `ssh` it will show a couple of lines like

> debug1: Offering public key: /home/foo/.ssh/id_rsa SHA256:hash
> debug1: Server accepts key: /home/foo/.ssh/id_rsa SHA256:hash

where you can view the key used from the client point of view.

At the server it should be logged at `/var/log/auth.log` like:

> sshd[1668]: Accepted publickey for `<user>` from `<ip>` port `<port>` ssh2: RSA SHA256:`

I suspect you will actually have the key appearing on `authorized_keys`, perhaps in `~/.ssh/id_rsa` or similar (they are loeaded by default). If you want to use the key provided, and only that one, even if there are other public key files, or keys on the agent, you should also set `IdentitiesOnly=yes`, e.g.

```bsh
ssh -oIdentitiesOnly=yes -i key.pem ec2-user@server
```

Although for hosts you frequently connect to, I would recommend setting that up on `~/.ssh/ssh_config`:

```
Host server
User ec2-user
IdentitiesOnly yes
IdentityFile key.pem
```

so you can just do `ssh server`

Comment: I was playing around with `-v` yesterday, and I got lines like:
debug1: Will attempt key:  RSA SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx agent
debug1: Will attempt key:  RSA SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx agent

But no actual paths to keys.

Comment: Using the `IdentitiesOnly` flag helped me to narrow down which key was working and which one wasn't, thanks!

Comment: the slightly different output with no path is probably that you were using an older version than mine. Glad you found out!